# Can't retrieve Firebase App Installation ID for in app messaging flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I have followed the steps mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?hl=en&authuser=0&_gl=1*o26qiv*_ga*MTY3MDU2ODM2NS4xNjIwNjY1ODcw*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTY4NjgxNjU3My4xMjUuMS4xNjg2ODE4MjkwLjAuMC4w&platform=flutter#send_a_test_message) to be able to test `firebase_in_app_messaging` inside my Flutter app.

However, i have **no logs** on **Android** when i run my app and on **iOS** i have this log :

```
10.7.0 - [FirebaseInAppMessaging][I-IAM180004] Runtime is already active, resume is just a no-op
```

But i have no installation ID to provide to the Firebase console.

The steps mentioned in the documentation are (very) simple so i don't think it comes from this

EDIT : I have tried to delete / reinstall the app multiple times and i do see the same logs.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on my end by manually running the project within Xcode. All runs using `flutter run` or via VSCode's Run and Debug worked properly afterwards.

Just ensure that you added the `-FIRDebugEnabled` param on the correct scheme.

Try uninstalling the app and cleaning caches before running a new build too